# GIT: forgot to commit and have made new changes. How to undo new changes, commit then redo changes?

Tags: git

I have a file that I should have committed but forgot all about. I went on to make more changes to a file. What I want to do is revert to where I *should* have committed, do a commit at that point, but still then get my new changes back. How do I do this in the most economical way?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Just to explain the flow a bit.

- I have file.php which has been committed and is in a working state.
- I make changes to file.php which is the new production copy of file.php. This file is **not** committed, but should be.
- I make more changes to file.php and remember that I wanted to commit file.php.

What I want to do now is save my recent changes (so git stash may come in handy here, thanks for that!) go back to the second bullet point, commit, then continue on. Is there a way to get to that middle uncommitted point?

FURTHER EDIT:

I think the bit I'm not explaining well, is that there is **no** commit down for the second point above. In that state it doesn't belong to the previous commit, but a new commit that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "forgot to commit" you mean forgot to "push", then... there is hope :)

If you have commited your previous changes to the local git repo you can use [git stash](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html), to save the new changes in a "stash" and revert them. (you can use the same command to recover the changes from the stash.. see the link)

Comment: +1, stash gave me what I needed in the end. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to undo the changes, you can just use `git add --interactive`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what that adds besides being interactive?

Comment: It lets you selectively add a subset of your changes as separate commits

Comment: +1 for the link to the --interactive. I didn't realise that it meant you could patch incrementally.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't committed yet, you can use git stash for this:

```
git stash
git add newfile
git commit --amend # update old commit that should have had the file added
git stash pop # unsaved changes restored and merged
```

Otherwise you will need to commit the file now, stash all other changes, and use `git rebase --interactive` to move the commit back to where it should be in history.

Note that this will cause problems for others if you're already pushed - in that case, you might as well just commit where you are now.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just the previous commit, you can always amend it. Otherwise the most economical way is simply to commit the file separately. There is no harm in doing so unless you have a special reason not to.